# Чего не хватает или нужно заменить в коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Назовём число подходящим, если его запись в 15-ричной системе счисления содержит не менее 4 цифр, не содержит 0 и заканчивается на A3 или 5.  Определите количество подходящих чисел на отрезке [10000; 30000].
Ответ к задаче 1243, но я не понимаю, почему у меня получается другой (1327), вот код:

```
count = 0
for i in range(10000, 30001):
    d = 0
    if ((i % 15 == 3) and (((i // 15) // 15) % 15 == 0) and ((((i // 15) // 15) // 15) % 15 == 1)) or (i % 15 == 5):
        s = i
        while s > 0:
            if ((s/15) % 15 == 0):
                break
            else:
                d += 1
            s = s // 15
            if d >= 4:
                count += 1
                    
print(count)
```

Вот картинка, если код написан не табулировано:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkwD6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count = 0

for value in range(10000, 30001):
    if value % 225 == 153 or value % 15 == 5:

        num = value
        length = 0
        zeros_enabled = False

        while num != 0:
            digit = num % 15
            num = (num - digit) // 15

            zeros_enabled |= (digit == 0)
            length += 1

        if length >= 4 and zeros_enabled is False:
            count += 1

print(count)
```

а у вас кажется проблема в том, что вы делаете

```
        if d >= 4:
            count += 1
```

внутри цикла `while`, т.е. если у вас число состоит из 5 цифр вы получите `count += 2` в конечном итоге, а если состоит из 6, но 2 цифра 0, то вы получите `count += 1`, потому что один раз все равно увеличите счетчик перед выходом из цикла